# Animating WPF buttons from inside a style

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm currently trying to make buttons on my forms animate using WPF - this is part of a University course, so it's all about demonstrating knowledge rather than looking good.

We've been shown how to animate per-button, but since I want the animation to be the same on every button I'm using a style - something we've not been taught and which finding documentation for is like finding evidence of Big Foot, IMO.

My code so far is this:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonAnimation">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                 To="360" Duration="0:0:1"
                                                 FillBehavior="Stop" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                                 To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                 FillBehavior="Stop" AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                                 To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                 FillBehavior="Stop" AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

The TargetProperty="" values are incorrect, and for the life of me I cannot find anywhere online that demonstrates what should be there. The values currently there are what you would have if the animation was applied to each button rather than in a style.

How do I get this to work? What is the correct TargetProperty?

Comment: Did my answer below help you?! If so, please mark it as answer by clicking on the checkmark besides it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this...

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
```

...should be...

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

And the other ones:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
```

You might have to replace `RenderTransform` with `LayoutTransform`, depending on what you are using in your markup.

However, this will only work if you only have one of the two Transforms, i.e. `RotateTransform` **or** `ScaleTransform`. If you have them in a `TransformGroup`, things get even more complicated. If you have defined the `RotateTransform` as the first child and the `ScaleTransform` as the second child of the `TransformGroup`, then this should work (not tested):

```
(Button.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)
(Button.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.X)
(Button.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.Y)
```

However, you have to be careful when changing the order of the Transforms or remove one of them because this will break your animations...

Good luck!